# Vbscript to navigate to multiple URLs listed in text file

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a Vbscript to go through a text file containing different URLs and navigate to each URL using WshShell.Run. I am currently getting: "Object Required: urllist" Error.

Sorry I am new to Vbscript not sure where to go from here.

The urllist.txt is stored in the same directory.

Here is what I have so far:

```
dim listFile
dim WshShell
dim fName

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile(urllist.txt)
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Dim fso
'do while not listFile.AtEndOfStream 
fName =  listFile.ReadLine()

Return = WshShell.Run("iexplore.exe " &  fName, 1) 
'loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed quote-mark. Next line:

```
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile(urllist.txt)
```

Should be:

```
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile("urllist.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I added ""'s and also used the full path name and the resolved the issue